# iOS - UITableViewCell prototype view set to y different then 0 and can't change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I hope image helps more than thousands words:

[image: Image of prototype cell with Y axe set]

As you can see my table starts with end of buttons and I added prototype cell and for some reason I have now cell started with Y set to 65. I can't change and I don't where could be the problem.

Edit:
I want that first cell should started where table is started. There is some indent which I don't know why is there.

Comment: still I'm not able to understand your problem..

Comment: I tried to explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your tableview section height must be set to 65. Change it to default 22 or whatever you like

Comment: Nope, I have it set to 1 when I was looking for problem. In Table View Size I have set 38 for Row Height and 1 for Header and Footer.